# Effect of ThreadLocals and side-by-side classloading

Tags: java, classloader, thread-local

Assuming

```
class A{
         private static final ThreadLocal<String> tl = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}
```

If A is loaded in just one classloader on the vm, the value of t1 is obvious. But what happens to t1 if A is loaded side-by-side in two different classloaders ? Will the value be shared for a given thread ?

Comment: Each classloader has it's OWN instance of the class, hence 2 instance of t1. So 2 different. You can experiment by removing static part from the thread local, i.e. every object can see a different value per thread. You can look at classes are just objects ensured to be singleton per classloader.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question. As *Tom Hawtin - tackline* explained, you are basically creating to instances of `ThreadLocal<String>()`. Now let's have a look at how `ThreadLocal` actually stores the values (simplified):

```
public void set(T value) {
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(Thread.currentThread());
    map.set(this, value);
}
```

It takes some sort of a map that is bound to every thread and sets the value using `this` (myself) as a key. This means that if you have two `ThreadLocals` (created by different class loaders), they have different `this` reference, thus effectively storing different values.

All in all - you cannot e.g. use `ThreadLocal` as a workaround to class-loader local singletons and creating thread-local ones.

Answer (score 4):

Classes loaded by different class loaders are different classes. So it's effectively the same as having:

```
class A {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> tl = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}

class B {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> tl = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}
```